# Is thread::id used anywhere in the standard C++ library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

`std::thread::get_id()` gives you an implementation defined value which uniquely identifies a given thread, but the interesting thing for me is that there is a dedicated type for this, `thread::id`, is this type used anywhere in the standard library ?

A `thread::id` is used somewhere or in any interface that you know of ? AFAIK this type is used nowhere hence it looks like it's quite useless at the moment .

Comment: Not being used in the standard library does not make it useless. You could use it in your own code, could you not? :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff ok, but at that point you can just use any integral type for the result of `std::thread::get_id()`, why you are using a dedicated type for something that doesn't really requires a new type and you are also not using the aforementioned type in any other part of the standard library ?

Comment: I bet it is to allow the implementation to choose the type based on whatever the platform uses. 32 bit integer? 64 bit integer? Pointer? All of those fit within the current standard :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff which in turn makes the usage of this type a real question mark; it's a type that is implementation defined, unused with the exception of `get_id()`, and as a programmer I don't even know how to use this type because it's implementation defined so it can be anything .

Comment: @user2485710, no, it can't be just defined as anything. It's a fully defined class with defined logic operators and hash support.

Comment: @user35443 from the top of your head please offer an example where you will consider the use of this type . Yes I can hash it, so ... ?

Comment: _"It's implementation defined so it can be anything."_ <- You could say that about a class from any library.

Comment: @user2485710 ... so it can be for example used as a key for a container of threads. That is much more practical than generating random ID on your own or giving a name to every thread you work with.

Answer (score 10):

The purpose of such user defined types is to make things easy for implementors.

In many cases, you will be implementing C++ threads on top of existing code bases, OS systems, or the like.  These may have different types of thread identification.

With that type, the C++ std implementation is more likely to be able to expose the underlying thread identification value directly, or with minimal modification.

Knowing what thread you are on is quite useful in many situations from the client side, and implementing it without an id from the system is complex.

`std::thread::id` can be sorted, compared (in a totally ordered way, with sensible equality) and `std::hash`ed, all of which are useful with the `std` library.  They can be copied (trivially) and constructed with no arguments (for the id that represents no thread).  They can be turned into a string via `ostream <<`, with the only guarantee that the resulting string is never the same except for two `==` ids.

Any operations on them beyond that is undefined.  But, an implementation could make `thread_id` be basically a pointer, or an unsigned integer index in an array, or one of many different underlying implementations.  An implementation who accesses such information is doing something completely implementation dependent, however.

Comment: so for example if I'm under linux and I mix some Pthread code in C and some standard C++11 code I should get a consistent and predictable enumeration of the threads because the underlying threading platform is pthread anyway ?

Comment: I'd like to add that `thread::id` is an internal class which is used for storing an ID that is guaranteed to be unique for every thread, and the only way to get out its value is to get it in form of a text using `ostream & operator<<`.

Comment: You can also get the value to an integral type by using std::hash.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom That hash value doesn't have to do anything with the real value (ok, that's also true for the text representation - "unspecified"). But the difference is that hash doesn't have to be unique, whereas the text representation does.

Comment: @user2485710 no such guarantee, sorry: this is to make it easy for library developers.  However, you could examine your particular implementation and check.  And examining it other than through the specified methods is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

> Is thread::id used anywhere in the standard C++ library?

No, `thread::id` is not used in the interface of the standard C++ library.

It might be used in the implementation of one of the recursive mutexes, but that would be an implementation detail.  I do not know if any implementation currently uses it.

> AFAIK this type is used nowhere hence it looks like it's quite useless
>   at the moment.

Here are a few of the other types in the std::library that are "useless" by this definition:

- list
- set
- multiset
- map
- multimap
- unordered_set
- unordered_multimap
- array
- atomic
- bitset
- complex
- condition_variable
- condition_variable_any
- forward_list
- fstream
- reverse_iterator
- move_iterator
- mutex
- queue
- stack
- regex
- thread

This is not an exhaustive list.

---

**Somewhat reluctant update**

Me:

> Is your question: What is a motivating use case for `thread::id`?

user2485710:

> yes, that sounds right, with, maybe, a special focus on the standard library.

`thread::id` is sometimes used to map a thread to attributes or vice-versa.  For example one might implement "named threads" by associating a `std::string` with a `std::thread::id` in a `std::map`.  When a thread of execution logged, or throws an exception, or has some notable event, one could look up the name of the thread to create a message for the log, error message, etc, in order to give better context.  For example threads might have suggestive names such as:  "database server" or "table updater".

`thread::id` is more convenient to use than `thread` for this application as `thread` is usually needed elsewhere to control joining.

Another use for `thread::id` is to detect if the current thread executing a function is the same thread as the last thread that executed that same function.  I've seen this technique used in the implementation of `recursive_mutex::lock()`.  For example, if the mutex is locked and `this_thread::get_id() == stored_id`, then increment lock count.

As far as "focus on the standard C++ library" is concerned, I really don't know what that means.  If it means: "Used in the interface", then this question has  already been answered earlier in this answer, and in other answers:

> No, `thread::id` is not used in the interface of the standard C++ library.

There are many, many types in the std::lib that are not part of the API of other parts of the std::lib.  `thread::id` was not standardized because it was needed in the API of other parts of the library.  It was standardized because `std::thread` was being standardized, and `thread::id` is a natural part of the `std::thread` library, and because it is useful for the use cases such as those mentioned above.

The key difference between `thread` and `thread::id` is that `thread` maintains unique ownership of a thread of execution.  Thus `thread` is a move-only type.  This is very analogous to `unique_ptr`.  Only one `std::thread` can be used to `join()`.  In contrast, a `thread::id` is just a "name" for a `thread`.  Names are copyable and comparable.  They aren't used for ownership, only for identification.

This separation of concerns (privilege-to-join vs identification) is made more obvious in a language which supports both move-only and copyable types.

Comment: Fairly sure `deque` is "used" as the default template argument of several of the container adapters (and `cout` isn't a type) :)

Comment: @T.C.:  Fair enough.  List reduced.

Comment: this `hash` thing is getting out of control; yes I knew that even before posting, `hash()` is a member function of this type, it's easy to recognize the presence of such functionality, my point was more about `thread::id` as a type . It wouldn't be nice if the standard would implement something that given a `thread::id` and an `std::packaged_task` in the interface of a function could, I don't know ... , move a task from the thread you are in to the thread you are targeting ? Like a work stealing queue, more or less. It would be a function using `thread::id` for something useful .

Comment: My point is that the answers are all focusing on what this type can do, not on what this type is effectively used for . And yes I can use `hash` to build elements for containers but I can basically `hash` anything so this *hash thing* it's not really `thread::id` specific and it's not really focused on what I'm looking for from my question .

Comment: @user2485710:  What **is** your question then?  Or is your "question" simply a complaint about the existing design of the std::lib?

Comment: @HowardHinnant my question is what it is, the problem is that you ( as a plural, to pretty much all the people that are commenting ) are taking this from the "functional" side, you are trying to outline what this type can do as a single entity; on the other hand I'm trying to understand what is the potential and the real usage of this type in the standard library or why it's not a popular choice for the interfaces of the functions .

Comment: @user2485710:  Is your question:  What is a motivating use case for `thread::id`?

Comment: yes, that sounds right, with, maybe, a special focus on the standard library .

Answer (score 2):

> AFAIK this type is used nowhere hence it looks like it's quite useless at the moment .

A `thread::id` implements relational operators and hash support. This allows you, the user, to have them as keys in associative and unordered containers.

Comment: yeah ... but it's not really that interesting, I mean I can do that with pretty much everything, any object, I can hash pretty much anything . It's not really something that you can pin point exclusively to a scenario for tasks and threads .

Comment: Any other object won't have the guarantee that it represents a thread of execution. Which other object would you use for that?